# Android 1.6 ksoap2 "RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: java.util.GregorianCalendar..", while passing datetime parameter

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have to call .net web services in android using ksoap2 api.
My code is working well for passing parameter as String or int. But it showing "**java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: java.util.GregorianCalendar....."** while passing Calendar object as parameter. I converted date into string and parsed it into date object but it is not woriking.

Anybody help me.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 1.6 ksoap2 -java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: java.util.GregorianCalendar -Error while passing datetiem parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004183/android-1-6-ksoap2-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-serialize-java-util-grego)

Comment: Original question was removed here

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to pass the date is as string, but if you want to pass it as Date, then you need to write a class the Marshal interface and register the envelope. This basically tells KSOAP how to treat dates. You can consider this post:

[Implementing KSOAP Marshal Interface](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. Let me try your way.

Answer (score 2):

First put the code below for creating the MarshalDate class.

```
package Marshals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.kobjects.isodate.IsoDate;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.Marshal;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

public class MarshalDate implements Marshal
{

public static Class DATE_CLASS = new Date().getClass();

    public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name, PropertyInfo expected) 
    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
     {
        //IsoDate.DATE_TIME=3
     String Test1 = parser.nextText();
        return IsoDate.stringToDate(parser.nextText(), IsoDate.DATE_TIME);


    }
    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) 
    {
         cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "dateTime", MarshalDate.DATE_CLASS, this);
         // "DateTime" is wrong use "dateTime" ok

    }
    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) 
    throws IOException 
    {
      String Test="";
      Test = IsoDate.dateToString((Date) obj, IsoDate.DATE_TIME);
         writer.text(IsoDate.dateToString((Date) obj, IsoDate.DATE_TIME));
    }

}
```

//In your client code:

```
String result3="";
    try
    {

      String soapAction3 = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorldDate";
      SoapObject rpc3 = new SoapObject(serviceNamespace, "HelloWorldDate");
      PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
      pi.name= "Date"; // name of the parameter in your dotnet variable
      pi.type =  MarshalDate.DATE_CLASS;
      // add property with your  value, I use new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() 
      rpc3.addProperty(pi, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope3 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envelope3.bodyOut = rpc3;     envelope3.dotNet = false;
     MarshalDate md = new MarshalDate();
     md.register(envelope3);
     envelope3.setOutputSoapObject(rpc3);

     HttpTransport ht3 = new HttpTransport(serviceUrl);
     ht3.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
     ht3.debug = true;
     ht3.call(soapAction3, envelope3);        
     result3= envelope3.getResponse().toString();

    }        
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
     //if we get an exception we'll just write the msg to the screen.
     result3 = ex.toString();


    }

    don't forget  envelope3.dotNet = false; it is very important otherwise you will 
    send null date value to .net.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. `MarshalDate` is `org.ksoap2.serialization.MarshalDate` (from `KSOAP2`)
2. Method Param: Note the `param2.type =  MarshalDate.DATE_CLASS;`

   ```
    // Your date may have time too?
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
    java.util.Date date = null;
    try {
       date = formatter.parse(p_obj.LoginUser_Created_On);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       //My handler
    }

    ////
    PropertyInfo wsParams2 = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    wsParams2.setName("d_LoginUser_Created_On");
    // Set Value
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    wsParams2.setValue(date);//sqlStartDate);
    // Set dataType
    //wsParams2.setType(java.sql.Date.class); // do not work
    //wsParams2.setType(java.util.Date.class);  // do not work
    wsParams2.type =  MarshalDate.DATE_CLASS; // works
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(wsParams2);
   ```

3.Note the additional md.register(envelope);

```
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //Set envelope as dotNet
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    MarshalDate md = new MarshalDate();
    md.register(envelope);
    ////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply some more details. In general with dates you will need to know the format and pass it in and out as string (well.. thats easiest anyway).

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

Comment: request.addProperty("Operation_DateTime",cal);

Comment: You are passing it in as calendar. You need to pass it in as String. Look at the SimpleDateFormat class for starters.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat gives me date in string. But i have to pass parameter as datetime. When i convert it to date again, its date format remain default format.